# How-to find IP address of a web service consumer?

Tags: java, web-services, ip-address

I want track the IP address of the webservice consumer. Can anybody help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
msgContext.getProperty(MessageContext.REMOTE_ADDR);
```

Comment: Now I suppose you're using axis2. Please, consider to add some details to your next questions, otherwise it's impossibile for us to post the correct answer.